# UnittWebSocketClient iOS error

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.2

error on  build for ios device....

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/andre/Downloads/UnittWebSocketClient/bin/Debug-iphonesimulator/libUnittWebSocketClient.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/andre/Downloads/UnittWebSocketClient/bin/Debug-iphonesimulator/libUnittWebSocketClient.a
```

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WebSocket", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WebSocketConnectConfig", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

this is my answer.

1. checkout from this url : https://code.google.com/p/unitt/source/checkout
2. include [unitt\iOS\UnittWebSocketClient\trunk\UnittWebSocketClient] into your Project. (.h, .m)
3. remove libUnittWebSocketClient.a lib file from your Project.